# How to convert this date into a unix timestamp in mysql alone?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

This is the date: `2018-01-25T13:39:40-05:00`

 Its from an API.

So far, I did this: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-25T13:39:40-05:00', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) AS time`

But its giving me `NULL`.

 I think -05:00 is timezone. But T is, I don't know.

Maybe perhaps there is another way take out T and -05:00 and convert 24hrs to 12hrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the STR_TO_DATE function.

You can directly use UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

> UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value
>   of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC.
>
> The date argument may be a DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP string, or a number in YYMMDD, YYMMDDHHMMSS, YYYYMMDD, or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.
>
> The server interprets date as a value in the current time zone and converts it to an internal value in UTC. Clients can set their time zone
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-25T13:39:40-05:00') AS time
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2206f/1